# How to close custom chrome extension overlay when extension icon clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I built a custom overlay in React that appears on initial click of my chrome extension icon. The overlay is injected as a shadow-dom element at the bottom of the DOM tree. When it does display, it covers the entire view which is the desired the effect. Now, I'd like to close the overlay by clicking on the extension icon, but can't quite figure out how to approach this. I'm tryin to achieve the same close functionality as the Loom extension.

Here is the current flow:

- Initial extension icon click -> chrome message sent to content script -> content script triggers state change to display overlay
- Extension icon clicked again -> message sent to content script to get visible state of overlay -> message response sent to popup.js with overlay state -> if overlay is visible, send message back to content script to close overlay, else open it.

When attempting to close via icon click, I'm seeing in that overlayVisible component state reads as false even though it is open. I have a feeling I'm approaching state management wrong.